# How can I erase my Macintosh HD?

Tags: imac

I have already booted up my pc pressing Cmd+R and tried to erase the Macintosh HD partition, but I still can't do it

Comment: what PC do you have ? and what does it say that you can not do?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Disk Utility [it's in Applications > Utilities > Disk Utility] or by Spotlight Search.

Click on the Volume where your Mac HD is on. [image: image1]

Click on Partition tab and select the corresponding partition you want to erase. Now click on the minus (-) button in the bottom bar. [image: image2]

Note this option will be grayed out if you don't have more than 1 partition. Instead you want to erase the drive. Click on the Erase tab of Macintosh HD and erase accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but I kinda figured it out on my own. I had to click on the Macintosh HD tab and mount the disk, then I could erase it normally. I don't know why that happened btw